# Select 1 item from the filter in a pivot table

Tags: c#, excel

I'm generating an excel in a server that doesn't have the excel application installed, so I used EPPlus to generate the Excel and in the excel there are many pivot tables. By default, all items in a filter of the pivot table are selected but I need specific filters to have only one item selected.Is there a way to do that using EPPlus?

If there isn't, is there another library that could do that? I need a something that could search all pivot tables, search the filters for a filter with a specific name and make only 1 item selected in the filters with that specific name for every pivot table. 
If it's not possible in C#, is there another way to make a program that does it without having Excel installed?If there is, I could just run that program when the excel is done.

For example, I have a filter with 13 months :

```
Jan/2017
Feb/2017
Mar/2017
Apr/2017
May/2017
Jun/2017
Jul/2017
Aug/2017
Sep/2017
Oct/2017
Nov/2017
Dec/2017
Jan/2018
```

In the filter, by default all of them are selected, I want the newest one to be selected(in this example Jan/2018).

This is the class that I created to build pivot tables :

```
public class PivotTableFactory
{   
    private ExcelPivotTable _pivotTable;

    public void CreatePivotTable (Worksheet baseSheet, Worksheet targetSheet, string startRange, string tableName)
    {
        // Selecting All Range of the base Sheet
        String       baseAddress  = "A1:" + baseSheet.EPPlusSheet.Dimension.End.Address;
        ExcelRange   baseRange    = baseSheet.EPPlusSheet.Cells[baseAddress];
        ExcelAddress startAddress = targetSheet.EPPlusSheet.Cells[startRange];

        // Creating Pivot Table
        _pivotTable = targetSheet.EPPlusSheet.PivotTables.Add (startAddress, baseRange, tableName);
        _pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = false;
    }

    public void AddFilterField(string columnName, string fieldName, eSortType sortType = eSortType.None)
    {
        ExcelPivotTableField dataField = _pivotTable.PageFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        dataField.Name                 = fieldName;
        dataField.Sort                 = sortType;
        if (columnName.Equals("MES_REFERENCIA")) selectFilterValue("MÊS", 10);
    }

    public void AddRowField(string columnName, string fieldName, eSortType sortType = eSortType.None)
    {
        ExcelPivotTableField rowField = _pivotTable.RowFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        rowField.Name                 = fieldName;
        rowField.Sort                 = sortType;
    }

    public void AddColumnField (string columnName, string fieldName, eSortType sortType = eSortType.None)
    {
        ExcelPivotTableField rowField = _pivotTable.ColumnFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        rowField.Name                 = fieldName;
        rowField.Sort                 = sortType;
    }

    public void AddValueField (string columnName, string fieldName, DataFieldFunctions func = DataFieldFunctions.Sum, string format = "")
    {
        ExcelPivotTableDataField dataField = _pivotTable.DataFields.Add (_pivotTable.Fields[columnName]);
        dataField.Name                     = fieldName;            
        dataField.Function                 = func;
        dataField.Format                   = format;            
    }

    public void SetStyle (TableStyles style)
    {
        _pivotTable.TableStyle = style;
    }

    public void SetDataOnRows (bool dataOnRow)
    {
        _pivotTable.DataOnRows = dataOnRow;
    }

    public void SetDataCaption(string name)
    {
        _pivotTable.DataCaption = name;
    }

    public void setAutoFormating(bool value)
    {
        _pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = value;
    }
    public void printPivotXml()
    {
        _pivotTable.PivotTableXml.Save("pivotsXmls\\pivotFinal.xml");
    }
    private int getFieldIndex(string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < _pivotTable.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_pivotTable.Fields[i].Name.Equals(name)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public void selectFilterValue(string name, int valueIndex)
    {
        int fieldIndex = getFieldIndex(name);
        if (fieldIndex < 0) return;
        XmlDocument xDoc = _pivotTable.PivotTableXml;

        XmlAttribute attr = xDoc.CreateAttribute("item");
        attr.Value = valueIndex.ToString();

        XmlNode currentDoc = null;
        foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals("pivotTableDefinition"))
            {
                currentDoc = node;
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (XmlNode node in currentDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals("pageFields"))
            {
                currentDoc = node;
            }

            if (node.Name.Equals("pivotFields"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode field in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (field.Attributes["name"] == null) continue;

                    if (field.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals(name))
                    {
                        XmlNode itemsNode = field.ChildNodes[0];

                        itemsNode.InnerXml = "";
                        List<string> items = new List<string>();
                        // Add item tags
                        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
                            XmlNode createdNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "item" , currentDoc.NamespaceURI);
                            XmlAttribute tempAttr = xDoc.CreateAttribute("x");
                            tempAttr.Value        = i.ToString();
                            createdNode.Attributes.Append(tempAttr);
                            itemsNode.AppendChild(createdNode);
                        }
                        XmlNode createdNodeDefault   = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "item", currentDoc.NamespaceURI);
                        XmlAttribute tempAttrDefault = xDoc.CreateAttribute("t");
                        tempAttrDefault.Value = "default";
                        createdNodeDefault.Attributes.Append(tempAttrDefault);
                        itemsNode.AppendChild(createdNodeDefault);
                        itemsNode.Attributes["count"].Value = "14";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (XmlNode node in currentDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Attributes["fld"].Value.Equals(fieldIndex.ToString()))
            {
                node.Attributes.InsertAfter(attr, node.Attributes["fld"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created the function "selectFilterValue" that tries to select the value of the filter using XML but it didn't work.Please ignore the extremely rough way of selecting the XML nodes...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: There is no example because I dont have any idea on how to choose the selected items in the filters but i can post the class I'm using to create the the pivot table though I dont think this would help much.